# How find this complex matrix $B$

Tags: linear-algebra

Definition of a complex matrix $A_{n\times n}$:
$$\cosh{(A)}=I_{n}+\dfrac{A^2}{2!}+\dfrac{A^4}{4!}+\cdots$$

question: there is exsit  complex matrix $B_{2\times 2}$,such

$\cosh{(B)}=\begin{bmatrix}
1&2013\\
0&1
\end{bmatrix}$?

if there exits,you can find the matrix $B$.

My try:I can't any idea to solve this problem,Thanks!

Comment: Do you know then concept of "diagonalization"? *(And are you allowed to used it?)*

Comment: @GottfriedHelms If $A$ is diagonalizable, then also $\cosh A$ is; but the given matrix is not diagonalizable.

Comment: You know the eigenvalues of $\cosh(B)$.  Hence you know the possible values for the eigenvalues of $B$.  Now look at all matrices with those eigenvalues and see if any of them work.

Comment: @egreg: upps, so we should ask the OP, whether he/she knows about Jordan-Normalform and whether he/she is allowed to use it...*(I just came another example of this type of matrix and was reminded by my software, that this is not diagonalizable. *#_!hrrm*:! But it has a nice matrix-logarithm so I'm pondering how this could be made working instead...)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms I don't think this is solvable without going through Jordan form. At least one should know how to compute the eigenvalues of $\cosh A$ from those of $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is diagonalizable, say $A=SDS^{-1}$ with $D$ diagonal, then
$$
\cosh A=S(\cosh D)S^{-1}
$$
would be diagonalizable. But your matrix $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1 & 2013\\0 & 1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ is not diagonalizable. So if a solution exists, it must have only one eigenvalue and its Jordan canonical form is given by
$$
B=SJS^{-1}
$$
where
$$
J=\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda & 1 \\
0 & \lambda
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
We certainly have
$$
\cosh B=S(\cosh J)S^{-1}
$$
and
$$
\cosh J=\begin{bmatrix}
\cosh\lambda & \mu \\
0 & \cosh\lambda
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now, the only eigenvalue of $\cosh J$ coincides with the only eigenvalue of the given matrix. Can you go on from here?